# Flutter tapping textbox inside the WebView makes parent widget to refresh in iOS only

Tags: flutter, webview, textbox, reload, tap

I have a `WebView` widget as a child widget of a `Container` widget. Tapping on the textbox field inside the `WebView` widget makes the `Container` to reload from `initState()` level.

```
Container(
child:
 WebView(
     initialUrl: 'about:blank',
     onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
        _webviewController = controller;
        await _loadHtmlFromUrl(context);
     },
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     onPageFinished: (finish) {
        if (this.mounted && this._isLoading == true) {
           setState(() {
           this._isLoading = false;
        });
     }
   },
 ),
);
```

`WebView` is loaded with a dynamic Url.

User is unable to type inside the textbox as it keeps on reloading when tapping on it.

`Flutter SDK 3.3.7`

`WebView v2.8.0`

How can I fix this? TIA

Comment: Can you share the complete code? Despite trying various approaches, I've been unable to replicate this problem. The functionality appears to be functioning perfectly on both my Android and iOS devices. I'm using "https://www.facebook.com/" for populating the form.

Comment: @DharamBudh Thank you for the tryout and reply, I have posted the answer that worked for me by playing more with the codes.

Comment: Okay, great! 

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue and the solution.**

Previous route (screen) calls `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(...)` to navigate to the `WebView` screen route. I guess, since there are no navigation history, `WebView` widget go nuts.

I replaced the previous route (screen), to call `Navigator.push(...)` instead, and the issue is gone.